# function calls the var as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, undefined

I have this function in my javascript code:

```
function fillTemplate({ table_name, id }) {
  console.log("ID OF TABLES  " + table_name);
  return `
  <div class="noten_tabelle_permission" id="noten_tabelle_permission">
    <h1 id="member_name">${id}</h1>
    <table id="${table_name}" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Fach</th>
        <th>mündlich</th>
        <th>Klausur</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- Make content with js code -->
    </table>
  </div>
  `;
}
```

When I call this function with this(for example) `fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id);` and print out the table_name into the console it is undefined. Why and how to fix this issue?
When you need the whole code for understanding or fixing steps here is the whole snippet:

```
db.collection("classes").doc(data.readGrades).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const data = doc.data();
        const members = data.members;

        members.reduce((chain, el) => {

          table_number++;

          const html = fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id);
          document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

            return chain.then(() =>
                db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        const data = doc.data();

                        addToTable("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);
                    });
                })
            )
        }, Promise.resolve());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: change `fillTemplate({ table_name, id })` to `fillTemplate( table_name, id )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your fillTemplate() function you are requesting an object {}

You need to replace:-

```
function fillTemplate({ table_name, id }) {
```

with

```
function fillTemplate(table_name, id) {
```

This should resolve the issue you are having.

Comment: To add to this, when you have curly braces in your function definition like you have, you are actually destructing a single argument into the variables `table_name` and `id`. You can make the change suggested in this answer if you wish to use two arguments. Alternatively you can change the function call to pass in the object `fillTemplate({ table_name: 'my table name', id: 'myID' })`